# GCC 4.8 gdwarf2 can not work

Tags: gcc

My gdb version is 6.6, gcc version is 4.8. I know that `gcc -g` by default uses dwarf-4 format, but gcc manual says that adding `-gdwarf-2` option can use older dwarf format. I tried it, but it is not ok. When I use gdb, it still reports:

```
Dwarf Error: wrong version in compilation unit header (is 4, should be 2)
```

Comment: You should probably rebuild you app from scratch with `-gdwarf-2` option.

Comment: $ g++ -g -gdwarf-2 -o test test.cpp, It's my gcc command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [GCC 4.5 Release Notes](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.5/changes.html) you should use `-gdwarf-2 -gstrict-dwarf` options to completely disable use of DWARF4 features:

> GCC now generates unwind info also for epilogues. DWARF debuginfo
>   generated by GCC now uses more features of DWARF3 than before, and
>   also some DWARF4 features. GDB older than 7.0 is not able to handle
>   either of these, so to debug GCC 4.5 generated binaries or libraries
>   GDB 7.0 or later is needed. You can disable use of DWARF4 features
>   with the -gdwarf-3 -gstrict-dwarf options, or use -gdwarf-2
>   -gstrict-dwarf to restrict GCC to just DWARF2, but epilogue unwind info is emitted unconditionally whenever unwind info is emitted.